# A "direct geometric argument" that Z(SO(3)) is the trivial group.

Tags: geometry, lie-groups

My question pertains to a "direct geometric argument" that Z(SO(3)) is the trivial group, as articulated in Exercises 3.5.4 and 3.5.5 of John Stillwell's *Naive Lie Theory*. The first exercise establishes that no rotation about the $e_1$-axis that is neither the identity nor the half-turn commutes with a half-turn about the $e_3$-axis. The second exercise establishes that there exists a rotation (such as, say, the quarter-turn about the $e_3$-axis) that does not commute with the half-turn about the $e_1$-axis. These two facts obviously imply that no non-identity rotation about the $e_1$-axis belongs to $Z(SO(3))$. But my question is why this implies that $Z(SO(3))$ is trivial.

Comment: $SO(3)$ consists solely of rotations and any rotation is conjugate to a rotation about the $e_1$-axis.

Comment: @Menander We know that $Z(SO(3))$ contains no non-identity rotation about the $e_1$ axis, but there's nothing "special" about the $e_1$ axis in particular so the same ultimately holds for a rotation about any axis.

Comment: @RobArthan Many thanks for your reply. Am I correct to say that any rotation is conjugate to a rotation about the $e_1$-axis because for any line $L$ through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$, there exists a rotation in $SO(3)$ that sends the $e_1$-axis to $L$?

Comment: That's right: if $\rho$ is a rotation about $L$, pick a rotation $\lambda$ that maps $L$ to the $e_1$-axis and then $\lambda\rho\lambda^{-1}$ is a rotation about the $e_1$ axis and is in $Z(SO(3))$ iff $\rho$ is.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Without looking it up, I can think of the obvious case where two rotations about the same axis must commute, but I'm not sure about any other possibilities...

Comment: @BenGrossmann Nothing "special" about the $e_1$-axis because of the conjugacy property alluded to in one of the other comments, I suppose. Thank you very much for your helpful reply.

Comment: @MenanderI Exactly. You're welcome!